# JxBrowser - How obtain same browser session in multiple components

Tags: java, swing, jxbrowser

I have successfully integrated JxBrowser into a Java Swing application. One of the views (BrowserView) is inside a JTabbedPane + JPanel. I would like to give users the option to switch to full screen in a separate JFrame. *Note that it would be very difficult in our project to have only one JFrame*.

How, for this second view, resume the already open session?
And, conversely, how to resume the full screen session when returning to the integrated view.
**Or, in other words, how can I have a single browsing session with two views?**

I tried to retake the Browser instance and / or the BrowserView instance to no avail. The best I got is by taking the same 2 instances in the JFrame. The context is taken over, but the integrated browser is crashed.

Here is an extract of my source code :

```
package testFiles;

import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.browser.Browser;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.engine.Engine;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.engine.EngineOptions;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.engine.RenderingMode;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.view.swing.BrowserView;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class PanelChromium extends JPanel
{
    private static final String LICENCE_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    
    private static Engine engine;
    
    private final Browser     browser;
    private final BrowserView browserView;
    
    
    public static void init()
    {
        String userDataDir = System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\ChromiumData";
        EngineOptions options = EngineOptions.newBuilder(RenderingMode.OFF_SCREEN).
            licenseKey(LICENCE_KEY).diskCacheSize(100_000_000).userDataDir(Paths.get(userDataDir)).build();
        
        engine = Engine.newInstance(options);
    }
    
    /** Integrated browser */
    public PanelChromium()
    {
        this(null);
    }
    
    /**
     * Second browser in separated JFrame
     * @param org First browser instance
     */
    public PanelChromium(PanelChromium org)
    {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        
        browser = (org == null) ? engine.newBrowser() : org.browser;
        browserView = (org == null) ? BrowserView.newInstance(browser) : org.browserView;
        
        add(browserView, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

I can instantiate many "new PanelChromium()" but "new PanelChromium(panelOne)" crash the "panelOne" instance.

Comment: I must specify that I am not trying to share the files (cache, cookies, ...) between 2 browsers but to obtain 2 views - in 2 BrowserView Swing components - of exactly the same browsing session.
Not sure that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution. Well, not alone... JxBrowser support is monitoring the posts on StackOverflow and has sent me a private email to give me the solution : contrary to what I thought, **it's entirely possible to move a Swing component from one container to another** - even a component as large as a BrowserView.
So I just instantiate one Browser and one BrowserView and move the BrowserView instance from the JTabbedPane + JPanel to the JFrame:

- JTabbedPane / JPanel.remove()
- JFrame / JPanel.add()
- (and conversely when the JFrame is closed)

In my case, it works well because the JFrame size and position are controlled and always overlap the JTabbedPane : when the JFrame is displayed, no one can see the "dead" BrowserView in the JTabbedPane. But if you follow my example, you should be warned that as only one BrowserView has been created, only one is active at a time.

*Finally, I want to thanks TeamDevs for JxBrowser and their quick and efficient support.*

Answer (score 0):

On googling a bit, it seems you can have 2 Browsers share a session:

> Two Browser instances with the same BrowserContext instances will use
> the same user data directory. As result they will share cookies and
> cache files. For example:  Java

```
BrowserContext context = new BrowserContext(
    new BrowserContextParams("C:\\my-data1"));
Browser browser1 = new Browser(context);
Browser browser2 = new Browser(context);
```

https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000012878-creating-browser

Comment: Seems like a good solution (I tried several searches on google but find nothing). I will check this solution soon.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Though it does not respond to my problem, your answer shows me that I must deal with the userDataDir option for multiple "Engine" instances.
I am currently using JxBrowser v7, so the init code is :
`Engine engine = Engine.newInstance(EngineOptions.newBuilder(...).userDataDir(Paths.get("/Users/Me/.jxbrowser")).build());`